# ItemDescriptionGenerator for vaadin TreeTable only returns null for column

Tags: tooltip, vaadin, treetable

Im using vaadin's TreeTable and im trying to add tooltips for my rows. This is how they say it should be done but the propertyId is always null so i cant get the correct column? And yes i'v run this in eclipse debugger aswell =)

Code related to this part:

```
private void init() {
    setDataSource();
    addGeneratedColumn("title", new TitleColumnGenerator());
    addGeneratedColumn("description", new DescriptionGenerator());
    setColumnExpandRatios();
    setItemDescriptionGenerator(new TooltipGenerator());
}

protected class TooltipGenerator implements ItemDescriptionGenerator{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public String generateDescription(Component source, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
            TaskRow taskRow = (TaskRow)itemId;
            if("description".equals(propertyId)){
                return taskRow.getDescription();
            }else if("title".equals(propertyId)){
                return taskRow.getTitle();
            }else if("category".equals(propertyId)){
                return taskRow.getCategory().toString();
            }else if("operation".equals(propertyId)){
                return taskRow.getOperation().toString();
            }else if("resourcePointer".equals(propertyId)){
                return taskRow.getResourcePointer();
            }else if("taskState".equals(propertyId)){
                return taskRow.getTaskState().toString();
            }
            return null;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Smells like a tough one.. This might be irrelevant, but what kind of data container are you using? Is the TaskRow object non-null? Does the table render otherwise just fine? Did you debug the method that calls generateDescription()?

Comment: All other objects are pointing correctly, im using my own data container that implements Hierarchical container interface. The container works great in all other ways, just not this.

Comment: The JavaDoc for the propertyId of the method `generateDescription` says: `The propertyId of the cell, null when getting row description`. Could this be related? But there's an alternate solution: why don't you create e.g. a Label in each column generator and don't set the description to it?

Answer (score 1):

I have passed the source object as the itemId when adding an item to the tree.

```
Node node = ...;
Item item = tree.addItem(node);
```

this uses the object "node" as the id. Which then allows me to cast itemId as an instance of Node in the generateDescription method.

```
public String generateDescription(Component source, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
    if (itemId instanceof Node) {
        Node node = (Node) itemId;
        ...
```

Maybe not the best solution, but it Works for me. Then again, I am adding items directly to the tree rather than using a DataContainer.